# Is there a standard or easy way to freeze a JavaBean?

Tags: java, javabeans

I find myself in the unfortunate position of using a lot of JavaBeans. I say unfortunate because I don't like that they are mutable. So after I create the beans (I am converting them from JSON using Jackson), I would like to "freeze" the beans at a specified moment to ensure they aren't mutated down the line.

I don't have the capacity to write Mutable/Immutable versions of each and every bean, nor custom Jackson factories, so I'm looking for a library or function call much like `Collections.unmodifiableCollection(...);` but for beans.

(Yes I know that is not *truly* freezing it if the original bean gets leaked. But I'll wrap or freeze them right after creation and never use the original again.)

Any ideas?

Comment: may i ask why you want to do this?  what is the use case scenario?

Comment: As mentioned, I am parsing JSON -> JavaBeans (a lot of different kinds). After parsing, I want to ensure they are immutable data objects that I can pass around the system. I don't like using "convention" of not using setters because eventually someone will forget the "convention." So I want it to be ensured that they are immutable.

Comment: +1, answer for this would be very useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you beans interface based or pojos ?  If they're interface based, you could simply write a utility method:

```
public class ImmutableBean {
    public static <T> T makeImmutable(T t) { ... }
}
```

You could then create a java.lang.Proxy instance which would either be specific to your bean, or look for patterns like methods starting with "set", and throw some particular exception.  Here's a good short tutorial on creating a proxy instance:  http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t18631.html

If they are pojo's, you should be able to use a library like javassist or cglib to create an enhanced version where your setters are stubbed to throw an exception.

Here's a javassist example:

```
 public static <T> T makeImmutable(final T t) throws NotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    MethodHandler mh = new MethodHandler() {
        @Override
        public Object invoke(java.lang.Object self, java.lang.reflect.Method thisMethod, java.lang.reflect.Method proceed, java.lang.Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            if (thisMethod.getName().startsWith("set")) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
            return proceed.invoke(t, args);
        }

    };

    ProxyFactory proxyFactory = new ProxyFactory();
    proxyFactory.setSuperclass(t.getClass());
    Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) proxyFactory.createClass();
    T instance = clazz.newInstance();
    ((ProxyObject)instance).setHandler(mh);

    return instance;

}
```

This does however, this will require that your original class have a no-arg constructor, so you might have to do a specific method for your class if you don't have a no arg constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Google found this when I searched on "java beans jackson immutable":

http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2010/08/entry_409.html

I don't know if it works, but the article claims to be able to do it.

Comment: But without the setters Jackson cannot create the beans. I'm looking for a solution that will this without having to write custom parsers/converters because I have a lot of bean types going through the system.

Comment: You don't need setters if you use a constructor that takes all the properties.

Comment: You still need them if you intend a mutable object.  Necessary, but not sufficient.

Comment: Nice! Several of those will work beautifully. Too bad it didn't come up in my google searches - I was too fixated on freezing because I thought there had to be setters

Comment: @AdamVandenberg - that only works if the framework understands how to introspect and use constructors with arguments.  And there is a fundamental problem working out how to map between named properties and constructor parameters ... based on the information available via Java reflection.